# how to pass the results of a function from one component to another in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, react-props

I have a component that runs a function and returns a result but I need the rest of my components to access that data from the function. How would I be able to do that?

Here is my app.js that contains the components. This is an example but my question is how would I run a function in Camera component and then reference the data in the Display component.

```
  export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
            <View>
              <Camera />
            </View>
            <View>
              <Display />
            </View>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the data as a state in the parent component and pass it as a prop to `Display`, and allow `Camera` to alter the state through a callback (`setData` in the example below).

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Camera setData={(data) => this.setState({ data })} />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Display data={this.state.data} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Camera = props => <Button onPress={() => props.setData(...)} />
const Display = props => <Text>{props.data}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Display component is dependant on Camera components data, I would suggest you add Display component as a child in Camera component.
You can achieve this by:

- Keeping state for Camera component,
- update the state in a function based on some activity (e.g. button click)
- In your Camera component's render() method, only when you have desired data available in the state,  mount Display component.
- Pass the desired data to Display component via props.

e.g.

> Camera component

```
class Camera extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           data: null
       }       
    }

    foo = () => this.setState({data: 'new_data'});

    render() {
         const { data } = this.state;
         const dataPresent = data !== null;
         return (
          {
             !dataPresent && ( 
                <button value="set data" onClick={() => this.foo() />                
          )}
          { 
             dataPresent && ( 
                <Display data={data} /> 
          )}
        );
}
```

}

> Display Component

```
const Display = (props) => <div> <span> { props.data } </span> </div>
```

If you would still like to pass/use data from one component in another component, with both components at the same level, you either need to have state for parent component or have a global store like ***Redux*** to keep data in one place and access it in Display component.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use redux, it simplifies stuff a lot, and do not need level up or pass state to parent/child

In your case you will need to pass props in Camera and Display component